# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this question has already asked. I tried a lot. but won't works. If i have the `.div1` its working fine. but i removed `.div1`. Console through error like below. How can solve this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fykxh387/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">Console error</div>
<!-- <div class="div1">Working</div>-->
<div class="div2">2</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function resize() {
var position= $('.div1').offset();
var top= position.top;
    var newtop = top + 60 + "px";
    $('.div2').css( {
        'top': newtop 
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(){
   resize();
});

window.onload = resize();
```

**CSS**

```
.div1
{
    position:fixed;
    top: 40px;
}
.div2
{
    position:fixed;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fykxh387/2/)**

Comment: `.div1` doesn't exist, so trying to access a property of `null` is always going to cause an error. I'm not sure what the issue is here...?

Comment: Rename the class `div` to `div1`

Comment: `position` is trying to find the offset of `div1`, but as you have deleted it, it cannot find it. I'd suggest either keeping `div1`, or putting in an if statement that checks if `div1` exists.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, You are correct. I don't know where i use null. Sorry I am new to Jquery. Can you solve this in fiddle.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @TommyJinks, Any body please correct my code. I really tried some condition its won't works.

Comment: @Azzah I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test whether the selector matched anything.

```
function resize() {
    var position= $('.div1').offset();
    if (position) {
        var top= position.top;
        var newtop = top + 60 + "px";
        $('.div2').css( {
            'top': newtop 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you are attempting to get the `offset()` of an element which does not exist in the DOM, therefore `null` is being returned. You are then trying to retrieve a property from the `null` value which causes an error.

Instead, when assigining the value to `top`, you need to check that `position` is assigned correctly. Try this:

```
var top = position ? position.top : 0;
```

Note that this will set top to the value of `position.top` if available, otherwise it will be set to `0`.

Comment: thank you. If we mention position top: 0 its automattically added  60px to div2.

Answer (score -1):

Do not strike out 
`div with class="div1" ...`
Your jquery is targeting that div.

```
<div class="div">Console error</div>
<div class="div1">Working</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
```